# Syntax for a Checked List Box

Tags: vb.net

I have checkedlistbox 1 and 2.

I need to be able to run some XML code based upon the item selected in each checkedlistbox simultaneously.

What would the syntax be for something like:

```
For each item in checkedboxlist1.selectedItems

' run my XML code

Next
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For web development (ASP.NET) do this:

```
For Each item As ListItem In checkedboxlist1.Items
    If item.Selected Then
        ' Run your XML code here
    End If
Next
```

For Windows development (WinForms) do this:

```
For Each item In checkedboxlist1.CheckedItems
    ' Run your XML code here
Next
```

Comment: ListItem is not defined? What does that mean ?\